# How to set goals for phone call

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to know how to set goals for phone calls in Google Analytics.

For instance, when someone calls our hotline via our website (devtraco.com), I'd like the ability to track such hits. I tried setting up a goal for this by using event conditions but I'm being asked to provide a category name, action, and label.

I'm not sure what to fill in these fields so kindly help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The google-analytics tag has 16.5k questions and 3.4k watchers. This doesn't feel off topic within that tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can track click on phone number as a event and then set it up as a goal. If you need to track happened phone call, you need Call Tracking (some third-party service).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your site is sending GA events for `tel` links, then you first need to find the event category that is being set. This can be found on the main Events page:

[image]

Now you can create a custom goal from the Admin screen that counts events with that category. Leave all the other fields blank except category.

[image]

As noted, this will give you the number of times your `tel` links are clicked. If you want more in depth tracking like call duration, you'd need to setup call tracking through a 3rd party service.